# Spring-XD: Kafka Connection refused

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka, spring-xd

I'm trying to use spring-xd to build a kafka consumer, but no matter what I provide for zkconnect, it tells me connection is confused

```
stream create kafka-source-test --definition "kafka  --groupId=xd-test --zkconnect=52.5.7.194:2181 --topic=vehicle-data | log" --deploy
```

this yields:

```
2015-05-22 17:49:46,973 1.1.2.RELEASE  WARN DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0-SendThread(52.5.7.194:2181) zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

this happens even though I have several other clients connecting to the same zookeeper instance, with globally available security

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Is Zookeeper actually listening on that host/port? Is there a firewall involved? Try using a network trace (such as wireshark) to debug the connection issue.

Comment: Yeah, it's starting to look like the outgoing traffic is being blocked at the network level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a result of a firewall blocking access between subnets

Answer (score 0):

> 2015-05-22 17:49:46,973 1.1.2.RELEASE  WARN DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0-SendThread(52.5.7.194:2181) zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

The exception indicates your XD container hasn't registered with ZK as it has issues connecting to ZK. So, this happens much before your actual stream is getting deployed.

I guess you are running XD in distributed mode. Make sure your container server can connect to ZK.